# How to delete a cell in tableView by clicking a button in a cell? Using coreData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I create a ToDo List app.
I used tableView to list the tasks. And I use a custom class for cell. In cell contentView I have a label and one done button in it. I have successfully implemented the done button click action in my code. It works fine.

## Problem

When I click the done button it deletes the last added task. But not the clicked one. And when I retry to click the done Button it perform no action. How to resolve this error

## GIF added below, click link

[image]

## Entity class ToDo

import Foundation
import CoreData

```
public class ToDo: NSManagedObject {

    public override func awakeFromInsert() {

        self.created = NSDate()
    }
}
```

## MainVC

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<ToDo>!

    @IBOutlet weak var taskTextField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var toDo: ToDo!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

//        generateData()
        attemptFetch()

    }

    // to give view to cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

        configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)

        return cell
    }

    // custom function
    func configureCell(cell: ItemCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let toDo = controller.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath)

        // call the method on the ItemCell
        cell.configureCell(toDo: toDo)

        // done button click
        cell.doneBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.doneBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainVC.donePressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)


    }

    // when select a cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // it ensure it have object and atleast one object in there
        if let objs = controller.fetchedObjects, objs.count > 0 {

            let task = objs[indexPath.row]

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ItemDetailsVC", sender: task)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "ItemDetailsVC" {

            if let destination = segue.destination as? ItemDetailsVC {

                if let task = sender as? ToDo {

                    destination.taskDetails = task
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // count of cells
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // we check here if any sections then take info of them and count
        if let sections = controller.sections {

            let sectionInfo = sections[section]

            return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects

        }

        return 0
    }

    // column count
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        if let sections = controller.sections {

            return sections.count

        }

        return 0
    }

    // give height of a cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 70
    }

    // fetching function
    func attemptFetch() {

        // create a fetch request with fetching Entity
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ToDo> = ToDo.fetchRequest()

        // sorting area
        let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: true)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]

        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        controller.delegate = self

        self.controller = controller

        // actual fetching
        do {

            try controller.performFetch()

        } catch {

            let error = error as NSError
            print("\(error)")
        }

    }

    // when tableView changes this function starts listen for changes and
    // it will handle that for you
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

        tableView.beginUpdates()

    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    // this function will listen for when we make change
    // insertion, deletion .. etc
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        switch type {
        case.insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }

            break

        case.delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)


            }

            break

        case.update:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {

                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
                //update the cell data

                configureCell(cell: cell as! ItemCell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
            }

            break

        case.move:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }

            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }

            break
    }
}

    @IBAction func addBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if taskTextField.text != "" && taskTextField.text != nil {

        toDo = ToDo(context: context)

        if let task = taskTextField.text {

            toDo.title = task
        }

        ad.saveContext()

        taskTextField.text = ""

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    }

    // done button
    func donePressed() {



        if toDo != nil {

        context.delete(toDo)
        ad.saveContext()

        }


    }



    func generateData() {

        let task = ToDo(context: context)
        task.title = "alwin"

        let task1 = ToDo(context: context)
        task1.title = "rambo"

        let task2 = ToDo(context: context)
        task2.title = "monisha"

        let task3 = ToDo(context: context)
        task3.title = "wounderlist"

        let task4 = ToDo(context: context)
        task4.title = "presentation"

        let task5 = ToDo(context: context)
        task5.title = "roundup"

        // to save data
        ad.saveContext()
    }

}
```

## ItemDetailsVC

```
import UIKit

class ItemDetailsVC: UIViewController {

    var taskDetails: ToDo?

    @IBOutlet weak var detailsLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // to clear the <DreamLIst to < only
        if let topItem = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem {
            topItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

            // this is execute when tap on an existing cell
            if taskDetails != nil {

                loadItemData()
            }
        }

    }

    func loadItemData() {

        if let task = taskDetails {

            detailsLbl.text = task.title
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        detailsLbl.sizeToFit()
    }


    @IBAction func deletePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if taskDetails != nil {

            context.delete(taskDetails!)
            ad.saveContext()
        }

        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }

}
```

## storyboard, click link below

[image]

## ItemCell

```
import UIKit

class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var taskTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var doneBtn: UIButton!

    var toDo: ToDo?

    func configureCell(toDo: ToDo) {

    taskTitle.text = toDo.title

    }

}
```

Comment: is the UIView part of an UITableViewCell ?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Show the code for the itemCell and done button

Comment: ok I will add now in my question, done button code in func donePressed() in MainVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK Currently you are setting the selector of your done button to outside of its container (cell) this is bad practice in general, you are configuring the cell with a ToDo but not assigning the optional inside the cell, supposedly there to keep a reference to the ToDo.

In my opinion I would change this slightly so that you store the reference to the ToDo firstly:

```
func configureCell(toDo: ToDo) {
   self.toDo = toDo
taskTitle.text = toDo.title

}
```

Now on your cell create a Protocol, then configure the cell with a ToDo and a delegate, then on button press tell the delegate your button was pressed with the relevant ToDo...

```
protocol ToDoCellDelegate: class {
  func toDoCellButtonPressed(todo: ToDo?)
}
```

Now on your cell configure as:

```
func configureCell(toDo: ToDo, delegate: ToDoCellDelegate) {
self.delegate = delegate
self.toDo = toDo

taskTitle.text = toDo.title

}
```

and add a ref to the delegate in the cell:

```
weak var delegate: ToDoCellDelegate?
```

now change your buttons selector to a func inside the cell

```
func buttonPressed() {
    self.delegate?.cellToDoButtonPressed(toDo: toDo)
}
```

Then in your VC you conform to the delegate passing self in the configuration and implement the delegate:

```
extension ItemDetailsVC: ToDoCellDelegate {
    func toDoCellButtonPress(toDo: ToDo?) {
         if let t = toDo {
            //tell context to delete todo and remove cell.
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also add the cell to the protocol method, then call tableView.indexPathForCell:Cell to get the indexpath to delete.

Comment: passing the cell as a parameter is not the best solution (imagine having a cell with lots of data and such this will basically pass it over and over and do more memory work than needed), you should pass the indexPath as a parameter instead

Comment: Thats not exactly how it works, when you pass the cell you are only passing a reference to the cell, there is still only 1 cell ...

Comment: I added all things except last two blocks of code. Where I add last two blocks of code

Comment: ButtonPressed should be in the cell, so you will need to change the selector on the button to inside the cell and remove the selector changing in the configure cell

Comment: the extension should go in the ItemDetailsVC

Comment: where I put extension outside the class or inside

Comment: outside, it is extending the class

Comment: func buttonPressed() is in cellForRowAt? it pops an error about delegate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133563/discussion-between-alwin-and-seanlintern88).

Answer (score 2):

Ok so then you should create an IBAction outlet for your button in ItemCell and then create a protocol of this form :

```
 protocol  ItemDelegate {
func clicked()
}

class ItemCell: UITableViewViewCell  {
    var delegate :  ItemDelegate?
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    //call delegate?.clicked() where you have the gesture recogniser 

}
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 cell.delegate = self
 cell.indexPath = indexPath
```

Then implement the extension for your class:

```
 extension MyTableView:  ItemDelegate {
     func clicked(indexPath: IndexPath) {
     //dismiss cell for indexPath
     }
  }
```